# Ruby nested const_missing method_missing stack too deep

Tags: ruby, method-missing

I have the following class:

```
module APIWrapper
  include HTTParty
  BASE_URI = 'https://example.com/Api'

  def self.const_missing(const_name)
    anon_class = Class.new do
      def self.method_missing method_name, *params
        params = {
          'Target' => const_name.to_s,
          'Method' => method_name.to_s,
        }

        APIWrapper.call_get params
      end
    end
  end

  def self.call_get(params)
    get(APIWrapper::BASE_URI, {:query => params})
  end

  def self.call_post(params)
    post(APIWrapper::BASE_URI, params)
  end
end
```

I want to be able to make a call to my wrapper like this:

```
APIWrapper::User::getAll
```

I'm getting a stack level too deep error:

```
1) Error:
test_User_getAll(APITest):
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
api_test.rb:16
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: Not super useful, but I added it to the question.

Comment: There's no backtrace?

Comment: Nope...that's all it's giving me.

Comment: Try changing `APIWrapper::User::getAll` to `APIWrapper::User.getAll`. Does that change anything?

Comment: Tried that.  Same error message.

Comment: Show us your test defenition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After using the keyword `def`, a new scope is created, so the issue here is that the `const_name` variable is no longer in scope inside the body of the `method_missing` method.

You can keep the variable in scope by using blocks like so:

```
def self.const_missing(const_name)                                                                                                                             
  anon_class = Class.new do                                                                                                                                    
    define_singleton_method(:method_missing) do |method_name, *params|                                                                                                 
      params = {                                                                                                                                             
        'Target' => const_name.to_s,                                                                                                                         
        'Method' => method_name.to_s,                                                                                                                        
      }                                                                                                                                                      

      APIWrapper.call_get params                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    end                                                                                                                                                        
  end                                                                                                                                                          
end
```

You might want to also set the constant to the anonymous class you just created:

```
anon_class = Class.new do
  ...
end

const_set const_name, anon_class
```

Comment: That's a terrible construct: you open the singleton class to get self, which you then use to change the current class to the singleton class.

Comment: how else would you keep the const_name variable in scope and add a method to the class's singleton class?

Comment: self.instance_eval do {...}, although now that I think about it more carefully, when you use class_eval you may have to do what you did.

Comment: The class keyword creates a new scope, so the const_name variable will be out of scope

Comment: Yes, you are right.  Please accept my apologies. Just use instance_eval and avoid all that.  instance_eval changes the current class to the receiver's singleton class.

Comment: Actually, you don't even need instance_eval because there is a public method named define_singelton_method(), which will create a method in the singleton class of the receiver.

Comment: @7stud yes you are correct I forgot about `define_singleton_method`, I will update the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `const_name` is recursively calling `method_missing`. When you pass a block to `Class.new` the block is evaluated in the scope of the class. (See the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Class.html#method-c-new))

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  How do I fix my code for this specific case?

Answer (score 0):

Methods do not see any local outside variables. In your case it is const_name, which is triggering method_missing recursively.

```
name = "Semyon"
def greet
  puts "hello, #{name}!"
end
greet # undefined local variable or method ‘name’
```

You can name anonymous modules (and classes) in Ruby using `const_set`, and from there you can easily see the name. I'd also not recommend defining new methods for every class, this is what modules are for. Here is my short, self-contained example:

```
module Greeting
  module Base
    def method_missing(word)
      Greeting.greet word, self.name.split("::").last
    end
  end

  def self.greet(word, name)
    puts "#{word}, #{name}!"
  end

  def self.const_missing(name)
    const_set name, Module.new.extend(Base)
  end
end

Greeting::Semyon.hello # hello, Semyon!
```

Comment: By the way, I do not endorse this usage of constants in any real code :-)